# How Create Undertow server with async support in java?

Tags: java

I wanted to create embedded server in my jar so, it can run as from command, like executable jar to run web app.

I find that we can embed undertow server, but how to do it.

Comment: could you please show what you have done/tried so far?

Comment: See http://undertow.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boilerplate code to run undertow server

```
io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletContainer 
            servletContainer = Servlets.defaultContainer();
DeploymentInfo di = Servlets.deployment().setClassLoader(App.class.getClassLoader())
.addServlets(servlet("servletName", ServletClass.class)
.setLoadOnStartup(1).setAsyncSupported(true)

DeploymentManager manager = servletContainer.addDeployment(di);

manager.deploy();

Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
.setHandler(Handlers.path().addPrefixPath("/", manager.start())).build().start();
```